# Excel does not randomize

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very simple formula, please see picture.

(black color) Why excel does not randomize the returned values, they are all the same while, in my opinion, they should be different?

How can I tweak my formula, so that the random values returned are different?

I absolutely want to use a dynamic array formula.

If I remove the LET function (red color), which I thought might be the cause of my problem, the problem persists.

[image]

Comment: does this not work for you? `=IF($B2:$F2=1, 1, RAND())` - it seems to work for me but I think I might be missing something about the question (as the answer seems too simple)

Answer (score 5):

That is because RAND() is run first and that value is returned when the if is false.  It does not return an array.

[image]

That is why they invented RANDARRAY()

```
=LET(a;B2:F2;IF(a=1;1;RANDARRAY(ROWS(a);COLUMNS(a))))
```

[image]

[image]

Another option is SCAN()

```
=SCAN(0;B2:F2;LAMBDA(a;b;IF(b=1;1;RAND())))
```

[image]

Both of these options will work with a two dimensional range.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use BYCOL:

```
=BYCOL(B2:F2;LAMBDA(d;IF(d=1;d;RAND())))
```

Answer (score 2):

Found both of these functions works as well, `MAP()` & `REDUCE()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B7`

```
=MAP(B2:F2,LAMBDA(k,IF(k=1,k,RAND())))
```

---

Or, bit verbose with `REDUCE()`

• Formula used in cell `B8`

```
=TOROW(DROP(REDUCE(0,B2:F2,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,IF(y=1,y,RAND())))),1),3)
```

---

Two more alternative ways using `MAP()` suggested by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B11`

```
=MAP(B2:F2,LAMBDA(a,MAX(a,RAND())))
```

---

Or, you could do

• Formula used in cell `B12`

```
=MAP(B2:F2,LAMBDA(a,IF(a,a,RAND())))
```

---

Even when `RAND()` is not ran first, it doesn't return the array,

[image]

---

It is to be noted that in the documentation of `RANDARRAY()` function in **[Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/randarray-function-21261e55-3bec-4885-86a6-8b0a47fd4d33)** , has been clearly stated that

> RAND does not return an array, so RAND would need to be copied to the
> entire range!

Hence the functionality of spilling using `RAND()` will not work with `LET()`, we need to use `LAMBDA()` along with the helper functions.

[image]

---